# checkbox color not set..as desired

Tags: c#, winforms

i have added checkboxes dynamically on a c sharp form....
and they are disabled when the form is loaded...
each checkbox has red color by default... i have assigned it black programmatically ...
but when the form is loaded it is red...i dont know why this is happening....

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
         CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
         c.Text = i.ToString();
         c.Width = 120;
         flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c);
         c.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    flowLayoutPanel1.Enabled = false;
}
```

It gets Black color only after i enable the flowLayoutPanel....
I want checkboxes have black color even when the form is loaded...

Comment: try setting the forecolor before adding it to panel

Comment: my guess is that the form2_load is executed before the list is populated, by a small margin, therefore list.count will = 0, so i will not be smaller than the list count, so the contents of the loop will never be executed

Comment: RhysW i can get all the checkboxes on the form added...what do u mean to say i dont understand..

Comment: true, i was taking a wild stab in the dark, just ignore my ramblings :)

Comment: @RhysW: That's not what the question suggests at all...

Comment: have you placed a break point at the form 2 load event and stepped through the code to see if it ever hits the right piece of code?

Comment: what happens if you set the color before adding control to the panel?

Comment: one more thing if you set the panel enabled to false you cannot see the colour change...

Comment: sta thats less helpful than my posts...hes already been told that and tried it.

Comment: When the **panel is disabled** so are the controls within it, and the checkbox is exhibiting the disabled behavior.

Comment: i cant replicate this problem, the second the form is enabled the colours are correct (when its disabled none of the updates apply, like changing the colour from the defauilt)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. Change your code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
    c.Text = "";
    c.Tag = i.ToString();
    c.Width = 120;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c);
    c.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(c_Paint);

}
    flowLayoutPanel1.Enabled = false;
```

And in c_Paint method you can draw control's text (saved in Tag property)

```
void c_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Control c = sender as Control;
    if (c != null)
    {
        string text = c.Tag.ToString();
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = 
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(
            new PointF(19, 5), 
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(19, 5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a function to do that and call it after the `InitializeComponent();` in the form constructor. You should enable the panel first too.

```
public partial class YourForm: Form
    {
        public YourForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // put your function here
        }
```